# upstart script. shell arithmetic in script stanza producing incorrect values. equivalent /bin/sh script works

Tags: sh, upstart

I have an upstart init script, but my dev/testing/production have different numbers of cpus/cores. I'd like to compute the number of worker processes to be 4 * number of cores within the init script

The upstart docs say that the `script` stanzas use `/bin/sh` syntax.

I created /bin/sh script to see what was going on.  I'm getting **drastically** different results than my upstart script.

## script stanza from my upstart script:

```
script
    # get the number of cores
    CORES=`lscpu | grep -v '#' | wc -l`
    # set the number of worker processes to 4 * num cores
    WORKERS=$(($CORES * 4))
    echo exec gunicorn -b localhost:8000 --workers $WORKERS tutalk_site.wsgi > tmp/gunicorn.txt
end script
```

which outputs:
`exec gunicorn -b localhost:8000 --workers 76 tutalk_site.wsgi`

## my equivalent /bin/sh script

```
#!/bin/sh

CORES=`lscpu -p | grep -v '#' | wc -l`
WORKERS=$(($CORES * 4))
echo exec gunicorn -b localhost:8000 --workers $WORKERS  tutalk_site.wsgi
```

which outputs:
`exec gunicorn -b localhost:8000 --workers 8 tutalk_site.wsgi`

I'm hoping this is a rather simple problem and a few other pairs of eyes will locate the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I should have answered this several days ago.  I first attempted using environment variables instead but didn't have any luck.

I solved the issue by replacing the computation with a python one-liner

```
WORKERS=$(python -c "import os; print os.sysconf('SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN') * 2")
```

and that worked out just fine.

still curious why my bourne-shell script came up with the correct value while the upstart script, whose docs say use bourne-shell syntax didn't